# Python Pandas read_html get rid of nested span element in table

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I try to grab some stock data from a website. The german website onvista.de have all the information I need. Now I tried to get the stock data into a pandas dataframe.

Like this:

`url = 'https://www.onvista.de/aktien/fundamental/ADLER-REAL-ESTATE-AG-Aktie-DE0005008007'
onvista_table = pd.read_html(url)`

This works fine for other websites. But the onvista site has a nested 'span' element in the th element, which has text in it. How do I get rid of the span element in the th element, to get a proper dataframe, without the text?

So I tried it with beautifulsoup to get rid of the 'span' element:

```
url = 'https://www.onvista.de/aktien/fundamental/ADLER-REAL-ESTATE-AG-Aktie-DE0005008007'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
onvista_table = soup
clean_data = []
for i in range (0,len(onvista_table.find_all('table'))):
        table =  onvista_table.find_all('table')[i]
        for tool_tip_span in table.find_all('span',{"class":"INFO_LAYER_CONTAINER"}):
            tool_tip_span.decompose()
        rows = table.find_all('tr')
        for row in rows:
            raw_data = []
            for cell in row.find_all(['td','th']):
                raw_data.append(cell.get_text().strip())
            if len(raw_data)<9:
                print(raw_data)
```

the result looks like this:

```
    ['Gewinn', '2020e', '2019e', '2018e', '2017', '2016', '2015', '2014']
['Gewinn pro Aktie in EUR', '-', '1,20', '0,89', '1,91', '2,11', '1,83', '4,65']
['KGV', '-', '12,52', '16,79', '6,95', '6,24', '7,06', '1,45']
['Gewinnwachstum', '-', '+45,18%', '-60,00%', '-9,47%', '+15,30%', '-60,64%', '+80,93%']
['PEG', '-', '-', '0,49', '-0,13', '-0,65', '0,46', '-0,02']
['Dividende', '2020e', '2019e', '2018e', '2017', '2016', '2015', '2014']
['Dividende (netto) in EUR', '-', '0,00', '0,00', '0,00', '0,00', '0,00', '0,00']
['Dividendenrendite', '-', '0,00', '0,05', '0,00', '0,00', '0,00', '0,00']
['Cash-Flow', '2020e', '2019e', '2018e', '2017', '2016', '2015', '2014']
['Cashflow pro Aktie in EUR', '-', '1,63', '2,38', '0,63', '2,11', '0,54', '0,52']
['Kurs-Cashflow Verhältnis (KCV)', '-', '9,25', '6,32', '21,08', '6,24', '23,94', '13,00']
['Umsatz', '', '', '', '2017', '2016', '2015', '2014']
['Umsatz in Mio. EUR', '', '', '', '299,30', '412,80', '384,80', '140,70']
['Umsatzwachstum', '', '', '', '-27,49%', '+7,27%', '+173,48%', '+632,81%']
['Umsatz pro Mitarbeiter in EUR', '', '', '', '598.600,00', '1.294.043,88', '1.485.714,28', '1.851.315,78']
['Buchwert', '', '', '', '2017', '2016', '2015', '2014']
['Buchwert pro Aktie in EUR', '', '', '', '18,03', '19,16', '16,87', '9,76']
['Kurs-Buchwert-Verhältnis', '', '', '', '0,73', '0,75', '0,84', '0,76']
['Bilanz', '', '', '', '2017', '2016', '2015', '2014']
['Bilanzsumme in Mio. EUR', '', '', '', '3.779,00', '3.430,50', '3.076,20', '1.416,50']
['Eigenkapitalquote', '', '', '', '+29,48%', '+28,71%', '+27,19%', '+23,36%']
['Verschuldungsgrad', '', '', '', '+239,10%', '+248,20%', '+267,74%', '+327,94%']
['dynam. Verschuldungsgrad', '', '', '', '+7.340,49%', '+2.430,71%', '+8.958,80%', '+6.500,00%']
['Bilanzierungsmethode', '', '', '', 'IFRS', 'IFRS', 'IFRS', 'IFRS']
['Marktkapitalisierung', '', '', '', '2017', '2016', '2015', '2014']
['Marktkapitalisierung in Mio. EUR', '', '', '', '764,52', '691,20', '655,58', '237,00']
['Marktkapitalisierung/Umsatz', '', '', '', '2,55', '1,67', '1,70', '1,68']
['Marktkapitalisierung/Mitarbeiter in EUR', '', '', '', '1.529.050,36', '2.166.794,35', '2.531.214,90', '3.118.461,26']
['Marktkapitalisierung/EBITDA', '', '', '', '2,44', '2,19', '3,69', '1,37']
['Rentabilität', '', '', '', '2017', '2016', '2015', '2014']
['Cashflow-Marge', '', '', '', '+12,12%', '+24,37%', '+6,49%', '+11,86%']
['EBIT-Marge', '', '', '', '+104,17%', '+75,82%', '+45,79%', '+122,45%']
['EBITDA-Marge', '', '', '', '+104,57%', '+76,11%', '+46,04%', '+122,81%']
['Eigenkapitalrendite', '', '', '', '+11,37%', '+12,27%', '+8,61%', '+32,87%']
['Gesamtkapitalrendite', '', '', '', '+7,55%', '+7,26%', '+5,08%', '+10,58%']
['Cashflow Return on Investment', '', '', '', '+0,96%', '+2,93%', '+0,81%', '+1,17%']
['Steuerquote', '', '', '', '+9,97%', '+28,65%', '+17,40%', '+15,96%']
```

This is exactly what I want, only as a pandas dataframe. So please can someone tell me, how I can do this.

Kind regards,

Hoh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have each table into a list of lists you can add to a new data frame. Example data:

```
raw_data = [
    ['Gewinn', '2020e', '2019e', '2018e', '2017', '2016', '2015', '2014'],
    ['Gewinn pro Aktie in EUR', '-', '1,20', '0,89', '1,91', '2,11', '1,83', '4,65'],
    ['KGV', '-', '12,52', '16,79', '6,95', '6,24', '7,06', '1,45'],
    ['Gewinnwachstum', '-', '+45,18%', '-60,00%', '-9,47%', '+15,30%', '-60,64%', '+80,93%'],
    ['PEG', '-', '-', '0,49', '-0,13', '-0,65', '0,46', '-0,02']
]
```

Create data frame like so:

```
# get first list as headers
headers = raw_data.pop(0)
df_gewinn = DataFrame(raw_data, columns=headers)
```

Then repeat this for each table (Dividende, Cash-Flow, Umsatz, etc.).

Comment: Damn, thank you Dan. Really easy in the end. But one more question. Do you know a way without beautifulsoup to get rid of the span element?

Comment: @HoH I don't, unfortunately. I pretty much always use beautifulsoup when parsing html because of these kinds of problems. Also, remember that if you found this answer helpful, you can upvote it. I understand you are looking for another way to get rid of span element so no need to mark it as accepted (perhaps someone else knows a better way and we'll both learn something new).